# unable to resolve class MimeMessage, Session, InternetAddress

Tags: java, grails, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email in my Grails application. The grails version is 2.1.0, Java version : 1.6.41
I get below errors when I try building my project:

```
unable to resolve class Session
                  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

 unable to resolve class MimeMessage
                         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);


unable to resolve class InternetAddress
                         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
```

I have tried several suggestions over the internet. They don't seem to work. nOt sure if this is Grails specific error.

I tried referencing **mail-1.4.7.jar**, **smtp-1.4.5.jar**, **activation-1.1.jar** via the Build Path.

But no luck. The error is still there.

Please guide. Let me know if I can provide any other info.

Below is the code snippet :

```
package com.xyz.xyx.ReportsApp
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class ScheduleXYZController {
    def sendEmail() {
          // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
          String from = "xyz@domain.com";

          // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
          String to = "abc@domain.com";

          // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
          String host = "smtplb.domain.com";

          // Get system properties
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();

          // Setup mail server
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

          // Get the default Session object.
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          try {
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("another Test Mail.....");

             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText("Another Body of the mail.... <br/><br/>"+ params.body);

             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: I don't have experience with Grails but have you tried to check the dependency tree of your project? For reference, see [grails dependency-report](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.1.4/guide/single.html#dependencyReports)

Comment: Not related to the problem, but the 1.4.7 (and 1.4.5) version is pretty old. Also you should use the same version for both libraries. The error suggests that either you don't have them on the compile time path, or these libraries don't actually contain the referenced packages.

Comment: Try the instructions on the [JavaMail web site](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).

Comment: you have to add library dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy || see the examples here: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.2.5/guide/conf.html#ivy || also check this resource that helps to find libraries in repositories and shows how to config your build config: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7#gradle

Comment: You need to install the email plugin, not just reference random jars.